# How to bind textblock.foreground to a variable? (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, textblock

So I am hoping to alter my program such that I can run a function to check and see if the foreground color should be black or silver. I am hoping to gray out fields that are not "accessible".

My form currently looks like:
[image]

I was hoping to "gray out" the "No maintenance required" fields. But I am having problems with trying to define a binding element to the font foreground in my data template.

I've tried everything from trying to define an IValueConverter class within the main window code behind, to defining a window key resource, but it doesn't appear that I can do that within a data template on the textblock element itself?

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated. Thanks!

XAML:

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,2,0">

    <ListBox x:Name="allSites_LB" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Height="400" 
             Margin="20,60,0,0" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Width="945"
             Loaded="allSites_LB_Loaded" 
             BorderThickness="1" SelectionChanged="allSites_LB_SelectionChanged"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate >
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="-20,1,0,1" Padding="0,5,0,5" >
                    <Grid Margin="75,3" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="345" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SiteNo}" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" Margin="50,1" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MaintStatus}" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="16" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <Button x:Name="viewHistory_BTN" 
            Content="View History" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="52" 
            Margin="20,496,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="172" FontSize="20"
            />

    <Button x:Name="startMaintenance_BTN" 
            Content="Start Maintenance"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="52" 
            Margin="793,496,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="172" FontSize="20"
            />
    <TextBox x:Name="Site_Address" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Height="21" 
             Margin="51,39,0,0" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="Site Number" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Width="75" 
             BorderBrush="White" 
             IsReadOnly="True" 
             IsEnabled="False"

             />
    <TextBox x:Name="Address_Title" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Height="21" 
             Margin="380,34,0,0" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="Address" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Width="75" 
             BorderBrush="White"
             IsReadOnly="True" 
             IsEnabled="False"

             />
    <TextBox x:Name="maint_Title" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Height="21" 
             Margin="699,34,0,0" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="Maintenance Record" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Width="117" 
             BorderBrush="White" 
             IsReadOnly="True" 
             IsEnabled="False"
             />

</Grid>
```

C# Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



namespace SiteMaintenance
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    /**
     * CLASS VARIABLES
     * */
    private SqlConnection localdbConnection;        // Connection to Site Maintenance DB (LOCAL)
    private System.Data.DataSet allSitesResults;



    // MAIN THREAD
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // try to open SQL Connection
        try {
            localdbConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.localdb);
            localdbConnection.Open();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
           System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("local SQL connection unable to connect");
           return;
        }

        viewHistory_BTN.IsEnabled = false;
        startMaintenance_BTN.IsEnabled = false;
        startMaintenance_BTN.IsDefault = true;
    }

    /**
     * Load dataset into datagrid 
     * LAZY LOADING
     * */
    private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // init command object
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
        myCommand.CommandText = "dbo.usp_GetSites";
        myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.Connection = localdbConnection;

        // init data adaptor
        SqlDataAdapter sites = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sites.SelectCommand = myCommand;

        //init DataSet
        allSitesResults = new System.Data.DataSet();

        sites.Fill(allSitesResults, "tblSites");

        int tableCount = allSitesResults.Tables.Count;

        System.Data.DataTable test = allSitesResults.Tables[0];

        int rowCount = test.Rows.Count;





    }

    private void sites_DG_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String siteName = allSitesResults.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();

    }

    private void allSites_LB_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // init command object
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
        myCommand.CommandText = "dbo.usp_GetSitesANDCompletedDate";
        myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.Connection = localdbConnection;

        // init data adaptor
        SqlDataAdapter sites = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sites.SelectCommand = myCommand;

        //init DataSet
        allSitesResults = new System.Data.DataSet();

        sites.Fill(allSitesResults, "tblSites");

        allSites_LB.ItemsSource = allSitesResults.Tables["tblSites"].DefaultView;

    }


    // do not allow selection of maintenance records that do not exist
    private void allSites_LB_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        // grab the index
        int selectedIndex = allSites_LB.SelectedIndex;
        if (selectedIndex == -1) return;                //WITHOUT THIS CHECK, UN-SELECTION WILL CAUSE LOGIC FAILURE

        System.Data.DataRowView tempData = (System.Data.DataRowView)allSites_LB.Items[allSites_LB.SelectedIndex];

        // grab the completed date field
        String completedDate = tempData["CompletedDate"].ToString();
        String siteMaintID = tempData["SiteMaintID"].ToString();

        // remove selected index if completed date and site Maint ID is null
        if (siteMaintID != "" && completedDate == "")
        {
            startMaintenance_BTN.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            allSites_LB.SelectedIndex = -1;
            startMaintenance_BTN.IsEnabled = false;
        }

    }


    private String maintRequired(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndex = allSites_LB.SelectedIndex;
        if (selectedIndex < 0) return null;

        System.Data.DataRowView tempData = (System.Data.DataRowView)allSites_LB.Items[allSites_LB.SelectedIndex];

        // grab the completed date field
        String completedDate = tempData["CompletedDate"].ToString();
        String siteMaintID = tempData["SiteMaintID"].ToString();

        if (siteMaintID != "" && completedDate == "")
        {
            return "Maintenance Required";
        }
        else
        {
            return "No Maintenance";
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are generally two good approaches for you to choose from, when binding the Foreground color to a piece of data.  Depending on who you ask, different people will have different preferences.  So... here's both!

### First Method: Style with Triggers

This method basically identifies 'special' behavior when a certain set of conditions are met. In this case, we're changing the foreground color to Gray, when the status == "No Maintenance Required"

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" /> <!-- default value -->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}" Value="No Maintenance Required">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" /> <!-- special behavior -->
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

In this case, just assign your TextBlock the appropriate `Style` property.

### Second Method: Use an IValueConverter

This approach creates a custom "IValueConverter implementation, which converts your Text value to a Color.  From there, we bind directly to our text value, and ensure that the converter always provides the proper color.

```
public class MaintenaceColorConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public Color NormalColor { get; set; }
    public Color NoMaintenanceRequiredColor { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.ToString() == "No Maintenance Required")
            return NoMaintenanceRequiredColor;

        return NormalColor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MaintenaceColorConverter x:Key="myColorConverter" NormalColor="Black" NoMaintenanceRequiredColor="Gray" />
</Window.Resources>
```

In your TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MaintStatus}" Foreground="{Binding MaintStatus, Converter={StaticResource myColorConverter}}" />
```

### Improvements

With either of these approaches, it would be better to have a `MaintenanceStatus` boolean or enum value, and bind your styling conditions to that.  It's a bad idea to use string-comparisons.  That's just begging for trouble.  These examples used string comparison because... well... that's all that was available from your provided example code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I went with the second method as I feel this kind of logic is better left in the code behind (in my novice attempt to get closer to an MVC approach)

I'm still having issues with the textblock still not properly changing the color of the text. When I remove the binding, I can manually set the foreground color, but when I run the binding portion, the code behind is triggered and returning the correct colors, but the text color is still not being set?

Comment: Its as if one of the template items are overriding the foreground binding?

Comment: Sounds like you need a new question, with the latest code.

Comment: This helped a ton. I was only able to get it to work by returning `NormalColor.Name` though. Not too sure what's different for me...

Comment: In the end, I ended up turning the two public `Color` into `string`. Then I just return that.

Answer (score 2):

More than you asked for but this is from some existing code

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMaintenance}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gainsboro"  />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks Blam! I should have probably stated that I was hoping to abstract this portion out of the xaml and put it in the code behind. But if all else fails, I'll probably resort to something like this. Cheers!

Comment: Yes did leave that out.  The title is how to bind a textblock foreground to a variable.  But cool.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback! I went with BTownTKD's suggestion on implementing an IValueConverter although with some alterations in my code. I discovered I needed to define "local" scope in my window properties in XAML.

Also, I was discovering that the binding wasn't actually changing the text color. After stepping through the code and seeing that the method was being properly invoked, I then hardcoded the results returned into the XAML to make sure they were working (foreground="black" or foreground="#FF00000"). I noticed when stepping through the code that the return object was a "color" object in the original binding, and by me hard-coding the colors into the XAML, they were actually strings. So I altered the code slightly to add in a .ToString() to the object I was returning and VOILA it worked! Thanks again for the help!

FYI here's the updated code bits:

```
XAML:

   <Window x:Class="SiteMaintenance.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SiteMaintenance"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="600" 
        Width="1000">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MaintenenceColorConverter x:Key="MyColorConverter" NormalColor="Black" NoMaintenanceRequiredColor="Gray" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,0">

        <ListBox x:Name="allSites_LB" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Height="400" 
                 Margin="20,60,0,0" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="945"
                 Loaded="allSites_LB_Loaded" 
                 BorderThickness="1" SelectionChanged="allSites_LB_SelectionChanged"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="-20,1,0,1" Padding="0,5,0,5" >
                        <Grid Margin="75,3" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="345" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SiteNo}" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16" Foreground="{Binding MaintStatus, Converter={StaticResource MyColorConverter}}"  />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" Margin="50,1" Foreground="{Binding MaintStatus, Converter={StaticResource MyColorConverter}}"  />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MaintStatus}" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="16" Foreground="{Binding MaintStatus, Converter={StaticResource MyColorConverter}}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <Button x:Name="viewHistory_BTN" 
                Content="View History" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Height="52" 
                Margin="20,496,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="172" FontSize="20"
                />

        <Button x:Name="startMaintenance_BTN" 
                Content="Start Maintenance"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Height="52" 
                Margin="793,496,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="172" FontSize="20"
                />
        <TextBox x:Name="Site_Address" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Height="21" 
                 Margin="51,39,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 Text="Site Number" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="75" 
                 BorderBrush="White" 
                 IsReadOnly="True" 
                 IsEnabled="False"

                 />
        <TextBox x:Name="Address_Title" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Height="21" 
                 Margin="380,34,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 Text="Address" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="75" 
                 BorderBrush="White"
                 IsReadOnly="True" 
                 IsEnabled="False"

                 />
        <TextBox x:Name="maint_Title" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Height="21" 
                 Margin="699,34,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 Text="Maintenance Record" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="117" 
                 BorderBrush="White" 
                 IsReadOnly="True" 
                 IsEnabled="False"
                 />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



namespace SiteMaintenance
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    /**
     * CLASS VARIABLES
     * */
    private SqlConnection localdbConnection;        // Connection to Site Maintenance DB (LOCAL)
    private System.Data.DataSet allSitesResults;



    // MAIN THREAD
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // try to open SQL Connection
        try {
            localdbConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.localdb);
            localdbConnection.Open();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
           System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("local SQL connection unable to connect");
           return;
        }

        viewHistory_BTN.IsEnabled = false;
        startMaintenance_BTN.IsEnabled = false;
        startMaintenance_BTN.IsDefault = true;
    }

    /**
     * Load dataset into datagrid 
     * LAZY LOADING
     * */
    private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // init command object
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
        myCommand.CommandText = "dbo.usp_GetSites";
        myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.Connection = localdbConnection;

        // init data adaptor
        SqlDataAdapter sites = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sites.SelectCommand = myCommand;

        //init DataSet
        allSitesResults = new System.Data.DataSet();

        sites.Fill(allSitesResults, "tblSites");

        int tableCount = allSitesResults.Tables.Count;

        System.Data.DataTable test = allSitesResults.Tables[0];

        int rowCount = test.Rows.Count;

    }


    private void sites_DG_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String siteName = allSitesResults.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();

    }

    private void allSites_LB_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // init command object
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
        myCommand.CommandText = "dbo.usp_GetSitesANDCompletedDate";
        myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.Connection = localdbConnection;

        // init data adaptor
        SqlDataAdapter sites = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sites.SelectCommand = myCommand;

        //init DataSet
        allSitesResults = new System.Data.DataSet();

        sites.Fill(allSitesResults, "tblSites");

        allSites_LB.ItemsSource = allSitesResults.Tables["tblSites"].DefaultView;

    }


    // do not allow selection of maintenance records that do not exist
    private void allSites_LB_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        // grab the index
        int selectedIndex = allSites_LB.SelectedIndex;
        if (selectedIndex == -1) return;                //WITHOUT THIS CHECK, UN-SELECTION WILL CAUSE LOGIC FAILURE

        System.Data.DataRowView tempData = (System.Data.DataRowView)allSites_LB.Items[allSites_LB.SelectedIndex];

        // grab the completed date field
        String completedDate = tempData["CompletedDate"].ToString();
        String siteMaintID = tempData["SiteMaintID"].ToString();

        // remove selected index if completed date and site Maint ID is null
        if (siteMaintID != "" && completedDate == "")
        {
            startMaintenance_BTN.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            allSites_LB.SelectedIndex = -1;
            startMaintenance_BTN.IsEnabled = false;
        }

    }


    private String maintRequired(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndex = allSites_LB.SelectedIndex;
        if (selectedIndex < 0) return null;

        System.Data.DataRowView tempData = (System.Data.DataRowView)allSites_LB.Items[allSites_LB.SelectedIndex];

        // grab the completed date field
        String completedDate = tempData["CompletedDate"].ToString();
        String siteMaintID = tempData["SiteMaintID"].ToString();

        if (siteMaintID != "" && completedDate == "")
        {
            return "Maintenance Required";
        }
        else
        {
            return "No Maintenance";
        }
    }

}

public class MaintenenceColorConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public Color NormalColor { get; set; }
    public Color NoMaintenanceRequiredColor { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        if (value.ToString() == "No Maintenance Required") return NoMaintenanceRequiredColor.ToString();

        return NormalColor.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

}

I'll be cleaning up my code later with BTown's optimization, but at least its working!

Comment: This helped a lot. I followed the same example but still didn't have the foreground changing. I did your `ToString()` method and it still didn't work. Ended up returning `NormalColor.Name` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: In the end, I ended up turning the two public `Color` into `string`. Then I just return that.